# How can I load all items on a web page when using an HTML parser?

Tags: c#, python, html, web-scraping

I'm trying to get a list of all the items available for purchase on a certain web page. However, the web page only loads 12 items at a time until the user scrolls down and then 12 more are loaded. Is there a way, in C# or Python, using any open source libraries, to be able to "see" all of the items available without physically going to the page and scrolling down?

Using Chrome's developer tools, I can only "see" the 12 items in the HTML window until I physically scroll down on the web page and it loads more.

NOTE: I'm relatively new at C#/Python web scraping, so I appreciate any in depth answers!

**EDIT:** If I were to use something like Selenium, would it be possible to load everything programatically? If so, how?

Comment: What is the website? Would be easier to figure out if I can take a look. I am going to guess you can just replicate the requests being made when you scroll down. Sometimes they even give you the max pages, etc..

Comment: I agree with @antfuentes87. To give you a real answer, I'd need to be able to see the site. It sounds like the site dynamically loads data via a web API method. It might be easier to directly access the web method being loaded rather than trying to scrape the web site that is accessing the web method.

Answer (score 0):

The Web browser itself can obviously load more items, and a web browser is just a program, so yes, it's *possible* to write a program to do it.

But you'd essentially be writing a mini web browser, which is a lot of work.

Does the website itself offer a way to load more items at once?  i.e. some websites offer a link or a dropdown menu in the corner of the page that allows you to increase the maximum number of items shown.

Comment: Unfortunately no, the website does not have a "Show All" option or even something similar.